# Create an abstract class that extends AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I would like to create a middle abstract class that extends the AsyncTask to share code among the closely related class. The real concrete classes will extend the middle abstract class to define the detail.

For AsyncTask, I need to specify the params, progress and result. But, in the middle layer, I don't have any implementation detail. So how should I leave the detail definition for the concrete class?

//Middle layer that implements shared code

```
public class SiteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<?, ?, ?>{
```

//Concrete layer

```
public class GetSiteAsyncTask extends SiteAsyncTask<Void, Void, Site> {

public class ListSiteAsyncTask extends SiteAsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Site> {
```

//On middle abstract layer, how to define the params, progress and result to be generic. The result can be a Site or Arraylist of Site

```
public class SiteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<?, ?, ?>{
```

//On the middle layer, how to define the doInBackground in order to make it generic. It can be a Site or ArrayList of Site

```
protected Site doInBackground(Void... params) {
```

Thanks

Comment: "Site or Arraylist of Site" isn't possible since those have different object hierarchies

Answer (score 1):

When extending classes with generics, you can just re-define the generics in the sub-class and re-apply them to the parent class' definition.

If you want all parameters,

```
public class SiteAsyncTask<Input, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Input, Progress, Result>{}
```

If you only care about result,

```
public class SiteAsyncTask<Result> extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Result>{}
```

If you don't care about any,

```
public class SiteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{}
```